Compare two DataFrames and append the results side by side (getting performance warning)
I have two DataFrames, need to compare those two DataFrames column wise and append the result next to it.
DF1:



Claim_number
Claim_Status




1001
Closed


1002
In Progress



DF2:



Claim_number
Claim_Status




1001
Closed


1002
Open



Expected output:
DF3:



Claim_number_DF1
Claim_number_DF2
Comparison_of_Claim_number
Claim_status_DF1
Claim_status_DF2
Comparison_of_Claim_Status




1001
1001
TRUE
Closed
Closed
TRUE


1002
1002
TRUE
In Progress
Open
FALSE



The below code is working, but it is throwing performance warning "PerformanceWarning: DataFrame is highly fragmented.  This is usually the result of calling `frame.insert` many times, which has poor performance.  Consider joining all columns at once using pd.concat(axis=1) instead.  To get a de-fragmented frame, use `newframe = frame.copy()`"
code:
i = 0
df_mismatch = pd.DataFrame()
while i < len(DF1.columns):
    df_mismatch[f'{col_list[i]}_dev'] = DF1[Df1.columns[i]]
    df_mismatch[f'{col_list[i]}_test'] = Df2[Df2.columns[i]]
    df_mismatch[f'comparison_of_{col_list[i]}'] = np.where(
                 (Df1[Df1.columns[i]] == Df2[Df2.columns[i]]), True, False)
    i = i+1


You can first collect the columns in a dictionary and after the loop build a dataframe from them which you can concat with the existing one.

You can join the DataFrames and their comparison:
out = (df1.join(df2, lsuffix='_df1', rsuffix='_df2')
          .join(df1.eq(df2).add_prefix('Comparison_of'))
      )

Output:
   Claim_number_df1 Claim_Status_df1  Claim_number_df2 Claim_Status_df2  Comparison_ofClaim_number  Comparison_ofClaim_Status
0              1001           Closed              1001           Closed                       True                       True
1              1002      In Progress              1002             Open                       True                      False

You could also concat to have a MultiIndex (which you can further process).
out = pd.concat({'df1': df1, 'df2': df2, 'comparison': df1.eq(df2)}, axis=1)

Output:
           df1                       df2                comparison             
  Claim_number Claim_Status Claim_number Claim_Status Claim_number Claim_Status
0         1001       Closed         1001       Closed         True         True
1         1002  In Progress         1002         Open         True        False

post-processing the MultiIndex to have a desired order:
out = (pd.concat({'df1': df1, 'df2': df2, 'comparison': df1.eq(df2)}, axis=1)
         .swaplevel(axis=1)[df1.columns]
      )

out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}')

Output:
   df1_Claim_number  df2_Claim_number  comparison_Claim_number df1_Claim_Status df2_Claim_Status  comparison_Claim_Status
0              1001              1001                     True           Closed           Closed                     True
1              1002              1002                     True      In Progress             Open                    False

Variant if you want to add df1/df2 as suffix and comparison as prefix:
out = (pd.concat({'df1': df1, 'df2': df2, 'comparison': df1.eq(df2)}, axis=1)
         .swaplevel(axis=1)[df1.columns]
      )

out.columns = out.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}_{x[0]}' if x[1] == 'comparison' else f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')

Output:
   Claim_number_df1  Claim_number_df2  comparison_Claim_number Claim_Status_df1 Claim_Status_df2  comparison_Claim_Status
0              1001              1001                     True           Closed           Closed                     True
1              1002              1002                     True      In Progress             Open                    False


This seems to be fine.but I want the column in below order
df1 column1, df2 column1, comparison of column1, df1 column2, df2 column2, comparison of column2. is it possible through pd.concat or pd.join?

@Srinivasan sure, you can do whatever you want, I added an example (personally, I'd skip the out.columns.map(...) step and keep a MultiIndex)

can you give me the code for that ?

@Srinivasan I already updated my answer, make sure to refresh the page ;)
